# In Oracle Does the Location of where condition affects the query speed?

Tags: oracle11g, where-clause, partitioning

We have Oracle 11g. We have a 400 million row table. Say **P_SCHEDULE** .

Our table is monthly partitioned by a column which is named as **WORKTIME**.

One of my colleagues argues that the speed of the query is affected by the location of the where condition. So :

```
Select * from SCHEDULE where WORKTIME = ? and SOMEOTHERCOLUMN = ?
```

It is different from

```
Select * from SCHEDULE where SOMEOTHERCOLUMN = ? and WORKTIME = ?
```

He claims that oracle execution planner decides by the location of the where condition. So if it finds the partition condition first, it decides to go that partition and it effects the performance.

I am not a db expert but I suppose Oracle execution planner should be intelligent than that?

How you come across this kind of knowledge? Is it true that the location of the where condition effects query performance

Comment: It is very easy to check. You just need to compare execution plans. In general the order of conditions is not important.

Comment: I checked the cost and it is same. But I have somewhat unsettled experience that the cost is not the overall criteria of a query speed. Again I do not know the technical background.

Answer (score 0):

I could explain **(This answer in behalf of my previous answer explanation)**

For example

Employee_master table has below fields and records

**Employee_id -------------Employee_name ----------Employee_salary**

```
  1                     ABC                   11000
  2                     AXY                   12000
  3                     CBC                   13000
  4                     CXY                   14000
  5                     XBC                   11000
  6                     XXY                   12000
  7                     YBC                    5000
  8                     YXY                   14000
```

Query 1 - select * from Emplyee_master where Employee_name like 'A%' and Employee_salary > 10000

Query 2 - select * from Emplyee_master where Employee_salary > 10000 and Employee_name like 'A%'

Compare both , Query 1 will perform faster then Query 2

Reason - Query 1 will check 1st and condition in column and find 2 possibilities then check 2nd and condition and find 7 possibilities
               Query 2 will check 1st and condition in column and find 7 possibilities then check 2nd and condition and find 2 possibilities

while using AND gate minimum possibilities condition should come first.

Comment: By proofs I mean: execution plans, statistics, benchmarks etc. Yours is still just some imaginations that are possibly not related to reality at all.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, its affect the query execution in such a case when SOMEOTHERCOLUMN having less number of values than WORKTIME colomn. (because its AND condition)

When its satisfied the SOMEOTHERCOLUMN value then its goes for WORKTIME colomn value.

Means there are the case when its not satisfied the SOMEOTHERCOLUMN value and hence its escape the rest part of query evaluation.

For Example SOMEOTHERCOLUMN having = 3 values and WORKTIME column having 10 values. now consider our scenario.

Comment: Please refer my explanation in below answer